# Update Script through Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

My DB Context class as below:

```
Public Class DataContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
             MyBase.New("WorkOrderConnectionString")

    End Sub
End Class
```

And then I have a connection string in the config file of this DLL.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WorkOrderConnectionString" connectionString="Server=(local); Database=db1;uid=user1;password=password1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

I added two new fields to the class, and want to generate update SQL Script for it. But when I am using following statement, it is generate script for entire DB.

```
Update-Database -Script
```

What is the way so it should generate only two new fields.. something as below
Alter table ....Add column...
Using following Entity Framework Version!.

Runtime Version: v4.0.30319
Version: 6.0.0.0

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does a comparison to generate the script, so if you have an existing database you need to create an initial snapshot of it so only subsequent changes will be included.

Run this command to make an initial snapshot:

```
add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
update-database
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#option1

Now you can change your model and the script will be the difference between the last migration and the current migration.

If you have a series of migrations, you can use the -SourceMigration and -TargetMigration options to generate just those changes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script